# Azure Data Factory ETL Process

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, etl

I would like to merge data from different data sources (ERP system, Excel files) with the ADF and make it available in an AzureSQLDB for further analyzing.

I'm not sure where and when I do the transformations and joins between the tables. Can I run all of this directly in the pipeline and then load the data into AzureDB, or do I need to stage the data first?

My understanding is to load the data into the ADF using Copy Activities and Datasets. Transforming and merging the datasets there with MappingDataFlows or similar activities. Then they are loaded into the AzureSQLDB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fully requirement based. You can go for either ETL or ELT process. Since your sink is AzureSQLDB , I would suggest to go with ELT , as you can handle lots of transformations in SQL itself by creating views on the landing tables.

If you have complex transformations to handle , then go with ETL and use Dataflow instead.

Also, regarding staging tables, if your requirement is to perform daily incremental load after the first full load, then you should opt for staging table.

Checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXw1gPaa2-M) video for full load and incremental load .

Comment: Thanks. Im new to this adf Topic and pretty overwhelmed with the different possibilities. Could you give me a short Guide of the Steps with the different objects I have to use in adf to load data from source system and excel files, transform, join them and load them into the DB.

Comment: No problem if this is to much to ask for. But to be clear, the data I use in Data flows doesn't has to be in an Azure Storage while I transform it?

Comment: Data doesn't necessarily have to be present in azure storage, these are the supported source datastores in dataflow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#supported-sources

Comment: Thanks. In my use case I have to rebuild a qlik skript in adf. In this skript temporary tables are used to join parts of the different sources together. Is this manageable in adf? Do I have to create those temp tables in Azure Sql or are they manageable in the data flow itself?

Comment: The fact that you're linking to your own YouTube videos is something that needs to be disclosed if you don't want this to be treated as spam